# Android Cupcake (API 3) emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-1.5-cupcake

For laboratory I need to run android 1.5 emulator. Yes.. Very old version. Does anyone have emulator  image or idea how to stimulate it?

Comment: have you checked the Android SDK manager yet?

Comment: Yes, but minimum version there is 2.2

Comment: The oldest I see is 1.6. But I agree that 1.5 seems unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

In the Android SDK Manager, if you check the "Obsolete" box you'll see the 1.5 SDK is available, not sure if this will get you what you need or not, but it's a start.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
But not sure how, after API 3 instalation and computer reboot or after this file instalation http://www.filecrop.com/70027503/index.html

Safety will be first try install 1.5 SDK and reboot computer, othervise check this link by antivirus

[image]